# Passing nested classes to Invoke-Command as argument

Tags: powershell, class, invoke-command

I'm trying to pass a class object as an argument to Invoke-Command.

```
class A {
    [string]$str_a
    A($sa) {
        $this.str_a = $sa
    }
}

class B {
    [string]$str_b
    [A[]]$a_list

    B($sb, $al) {
        $this.str_b = $sb
        $this.a_list = $al
    }
}

$a_obj = [A]::new('a-object')
$b_obj = [B]::new('b-object', $a_obj)

Invoke-Command -Computername 'abc' -ScriptBlock {
    param($b) $b
} -ArgumentList $b_obj
```

When the above is executed, I expect it to print $str_b and $a_list from the object $b.

Instead, only $str_b is printed. That makes sense as $a_list is "pointer equivalent" inside an object of type B.

Is there a way to flatten this object before sending it to the remote computer?

Or any other method that could solve this?

Comment: Reference `$b.a_list` inside the Invoke-Command ScriptBlock?

Comment: It'll print type of a_list. i.e. A. Again, if you invoke this on remote computer. On the current system, it'll print contents of a_list.

Comment: And your goal is just to have it return `str_b` and every `str_a` property value in `$b.a_list`?

Comment: On the remote computer, correct.